# How is the AOSP project built?

Tags: android, go, android-source, android-soong

All the git projects for the AOSP are cloned by the repo tool, which reads this xml: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/refs/heads/master/default.xml.

[AOSP guide](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) says the in order to build, we should run `source build/envsetup.sh` on the folder where repo cloned all repositories. So let's look at the `platform/build` on the default.xml from the manifest repository. We get

```
  <project path="build/make" name="platform/build" groups="pdk" >
    <copyfile src="core/root.mk" dest="Makefile" />
    <linkfile src="CleanSpec.mk" dest="build/CleanSpec.mk" />
    <linkfile src="buildspec.mk.default" dest="build/buildspec.mk.default" />
    <linkfile src="core" dest="build/core" />
    <linkfile src="envsetup.sh" dest="build/envsetup.sh" />
    <linkfile src="target" dest="build/target" />
    <linkfile src="tools" dest="build/tools" />
  </project>
```

We confirm where [envsetup.sh is located.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/master/envsetup.sh), it is in `platform/build`. It defines the function `m` which according to the AOSP guide, builds the entire AOSP project:

```
function _trigger_build()
(
    local -r bc="$1"; shift
    if T="$(gettop)"; then
      _wrap_build "$T/build/soong/soong_ui.bash" --build-mode --${bc} --dir="$(pwd)" "$@"
    else
      echo "Couldn't locate the top of the tree. Try setting TOP."
    fi
)
function m()
(
    _trigger_build "all-modules" "$@"
)
```

Ok, so looks like `build/soong/soong_ui.bash` is the place called when we run the `m` function, so this script should build everything.

Here's [soong_ui.bash](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/soong_ui.bash). It sources `source ${TOP}/build/soong/scripts/microfactory.bash` and then calls `soong_build_go soong_ui android/soong/cmd/soong_ui`

Here's [microfactory.bash](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/scripts/microfactory.bash), where we find function soong_build_go

```
soong_build_go
{
    BUILDDIR=$(getoutdir) \
      SRCDIR=${TOP} \
      BLUEPRINTDIR=${TOP}/build/blueprint \
      EXTRA_ARGS="-pkg-path android/soong=${TOP}/build/soong -pkg-path github.com/golang/protobuf=${TOP}/external/golang-protobuf" \
      build_go $@
}
```

We find `build_go` in [microfactory.bash from build/blueprint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint/+/refs/heads/master/microfactory/microfactory.bash):

Looks like all of this is for building the [microfactory.go](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint/+/refs/heads/master/microfactory/microfactory.go) project. I think it has something to do with the soong build system.

I'm now lost. After building microfactory.go, what happens? Where does actual Android code gets built?

microfactory.sh says build_go does this: `Bootstrap microfactory from source if necessary and use it to build the requested binary.` The requested binary is `android/soong/cmd/soong_ui`

I'm trying to find `android/soong/cmd/soong_ui` but I don't know what/where it is, but I'd guess is the soong build system, not the AOSP project yet.

**UPDATE:**

on `soong_ui.bash`, I noticed it end with

```
cd ${TOP}
exec "$(getoutdir)/soong_ui" "$@"
```

Remember that this is called form `envsetup.sh`. Well, `${TOP}`, I guess, is the place where repo clones everything. Looks like it's trying to execute `soong_ui` with the arguments from `envsetup.sh` which are `--build-mode --${bc} --dir="$(pwd)" "$@"`, where this `$@` is  `"all-modules" "$@"`, I guess.

I assume `song_ui` is the soong executable. It should look for `Android.bp` on the `${TOP}`, but I don't think there is one on the place where repo cloned everything.

Comment: I'm wondering why AOSP build system architecture doesn't have open documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have already found out a lot, and you are right with the link from `m` to `soong_ui.bash` and then starting `microfactory`.

From my reading of the code, the purpose of `soong_build_go` is to build the package `android/soong/cmd/soong_ui`, with the binary name `soong_ui`. Like Yong said in the other answer, this creates the binary `soong_ui` under the directory [`$(getoutdir)`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/scripts/microfactory.bash;l=35;drc=b82471ad6dfec4790b2d86e49525dadc3fc06416), and the source for that binary is located at [`build/soong/cmd/soong_ui/main.go`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/cmd/soong_ui/main.go;l=120;drc=534f15708f8335b3ec0547445ec71c408191986d).

As for your updated question about an `Android.bp` file, it is [symlinked](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/3198b4d243a65a58edf68201a411874ac3a56b35/default.xml#29) from [`build/soong/root.bp`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/root.bp;drc=393667285ef6845a1cf4675b266158df544ce994) when `repo sync` is run, but as you can see, the file is empty.

Instead, in `m` it tells Soong to build [`all_modules`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/cmd/soong_ui/main.go;l=416;drc=master), which eventually runs another tool called [`kati`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/ui/build/build.go;l=261;drc=3c9f5ac787263055ed9de38502de5b0a4c142de5). From the description in https://github.com/google/kati, Kati processes GNU makefiles and turns them into [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) build files.

At this point we can (mostly) assume regular Make semantics, even though the underlying build system is actually Kati and Ninja and Soong etc. Since the working directory is `$TOP`, the `Makefile` at the root directory, which is symlinked from [`build/make/core/root.mk`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/root.mk;l=1;drc=6cdc5d20f346187a9926a7e9a2ccb07efc4ed3ff) is used. Which includes [`main.mk`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/main.mk;l=1402;drc=e47d6e4a8c89cae336c60db35b27d08380d77179) which then includes `build/make/core/Makefile`. Inside that makefile you can see how the different `.img` files are built (e.g. [system.img](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/Makefile;l=2577;drc=d21e7dc8334528247ae47ddb7a0f7fb52f387576)).

Comment: Note that it has been a while since I last looked at this code, and the system changed a bit, so it would be best for you to double check what I said above. In particular, I see `build/soong/filesystem/filesystem.go` being checked in very recently, which looks like it may replace some/most of the code path I described above.

Comment: I remember reading about Android.bp replacing several makefiles, but it looks like it's almost not used. Soong should build Android.bp files but all it does is to call Kati to build makefiles?

Comment: Android.bp files are used. From a build system user's perspective, defining a target in .bp is equivalent to defining it in make. If you look inside the source for [build.go](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/soong/ui/build/build.go;l=176-295;drc=3c9f5ac787263055ed9de38502de5b0a4c142de5), it calls a number of actions, including runSoong, runKati, runNinja, and runBazel. My (unverified) guess is that Soong turns .bp files into ninja, and Kati turns .mk files into ninja, and then Ninja takes both to build the output artifact. I don't know where Bazel fits in.

Comment: I can double confirm: Soong parses .bp into .ninja files. It's mentioned in Soong source code. Bazel is introduced only in recent Android versions (11, 12). So it may be not widely used yet.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take make systemimage as an example:

The call sequence is:

1. prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/makeparallel --ninja build/soong/soong_ui.bash --make-mode "systemimage".
   And $(getoutdir)/soong_ui is build by "build_go soong_ui android/soong/cmd/soong_ui"
2. build/soong/cmd/soong_ui/main.go#main()
3. soong/ui/build/build.go#Build()